# Metadata retention with Typescript, Babel 7, Decorators

Tags: typescript, babeljs, typeorm

I am using TypeORM with Babel 7 and Typescript and it seem that the metadata are not present in the compiled code. Can something be done about that or is this a limitation of using Babel ?

*The error*

> ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Photo#isPublished is not
>   defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an
>   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure
>   you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in
>   your application (before any entity imported).If you are using
>   JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column
>   type.
>       at new ColumnTypeUndefinedError

*Photo.js*

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export class Photo {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number


    @Column()
    isPublished: boolean
}
```

*orm code*

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import {createConnection} from 'typeorm'
import {Photo} from './entities/Photo'

createConnection({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'test',
    entities: [
        Photo
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
}).then(connection => {
    // here you can start to work with your entities
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

*package.json*

```
{
    "name": "typescript-babel-node",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "run-p -r dev:run type-check:watch",
        "dev:run": "nodemon --exec babel-node --extensions '.ts,.js' src/index.js",
        "build": "babel src -d build --extensions '.ts,.js' src/index.js",
        "start": "node build/index.js",
        "type-check:watch": "tsc --watch",
        "test": "jest --watch"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^10.12.0",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "pg": "^7.6.0",
        "ramda": "^0.25.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
        "typeorm": "^0.2.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
        "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
        "@types/jest": "^23.3.7",
        "@types/ramda": "^0.25.39",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
        "dot-env": "0.0.1",
        "eslint": "^5.7.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
        "jest": "^23.6.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.12.1",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
        "ts-jest": "^23.10.4",
        "typescript": "^3.1.3",
        "webpack": "^4.23.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Getting to this problem after a while I was able to find another Babel plugin for this, apart the one mentioned in the accepted answer:
[babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata](https://github.com/leonardfactory/babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata)
Seems to be working with TypeORM and Nest.

Comment: isn't your main entry file `index.js`? That should be where "reflect-metadata" is imported in

Comment: Not really possible as the curent babel plugin is implemented, it just removes the types. Would you be open to a custom babel plugin ? (Not saying I would write one, but might be fun to try :) )

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: I see no reason why not to use a custom babel plugin. It should however not reinvent the wheel and reimplement the whole TS support... :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth played around with it a little bit, I almost have a proof of concept, with some caveats. There is no type info so if we are to emit the type an annotation is required (an error can be raised if it is missing). Parameter decorators are not available (the babel version of decorators don't suport this as far as I can tell). Since there is no way to distinguish between a class and an interface, I need to emit smth like `TypeAnnotationType || Object`. If `TypeAnnotationType` is an interface it will be undefined at runtime and `Object` will be used. lets talk more on gitter.

Answer (score 15):

Out of the box this is not supported as is noted in another answer. We can however write a babel plugin to get it to work.

Writing the code is not very complicated, the problems come from the limitations of the information we have inside babel. Babel does not perform type checking on typescript. This means we don't have any semantic information, we just have the type annotation and what information we can derive from it. This means that our solution is by necessity very limited

Limitations:

- If no type annotation is present we have no type to write
- If we have a type reference, we can only use the type name, we can't check if the refence is to an interface, as type alias, a class or an enum. In practice this means that :

  - If the type is an interface or a type alias, the type name will be `undefined` at runtime, to avoid the undefined we can do `type || Object` to default to object if the type does not have a runtime value associated
  - If the type is an enum, Typescript would write `Number` or `String` in the metadata, depending on the type of the enum. Since we write the type name to the metadata, this means you will end up with the container object of the enum inside the metadata.

The type serialization can be copied from the typescript compiler itself with minimal changes (and it's really just two functions `serializeTypeNode` and `serializeTypeList` all about 150 lines of code).

For this sample class the results we get are:

```
declare var decorator: any;

interface ISampleInterface {

}

enum Flags { One }
class OtherClass {}


type ArrayAlias = number[]

class Test {
    @decorator
    untypedProp; // no design:type
    @decorator
    nrProp: number // Number as expected
    @decorator
    strProp: string // String as expected
    @decorator
    boolProp: boolean // Boolean as expected

    @decorator
    nrPropUndefined: number | undefined // Number as expected
    @decorator
    strPropUndefined: string | undefined // String as expected
    @decorator
    boolPropUndefined: boolean | undefined // Boolean as expected

    @decorator
    arrayProp: number[]

    // Type references
    @decorator
    classRefProp: OtherClass; // OtherClass || Object  = Object since OtherClass is still a class at runtime

    @decorator
    interfaceRefProp: ISampleInterface;  // ISampleInterface || Object  = Object since ISampleInterface is undefined at runtime

    @decorator
    enumRefProp: Flags; // Flags || Object = Flags since Flags exists as a value at runtime, here TS would have written Number/String

    @decorator
    typeAliasProp: ArrayAlias; // ArrayAlias || Object = Object since ArrayAlias does not exist t runtime and in Babel swe have no idea ArrayAlias is actually an array

    @decorator
    selfClassRefProp: Test; // Test || Object  = Object since Babel puts decorators instantiation before class definition, this is a quirk, this may be fixable
}
```

The actual plugin code is not very large (minus the methods copied over from the TS version):

```
export default declare((api: typeof import('@babel/core'), { jsxPragma = "React" }): PluginObj => {
  api.assertVersion(7);

  return {
    name: "transform-typescript-decorator-metadata",
    inherits: syntaxTypeScript,

    visitor: {
      ClassDeclaration(path) {
        var node = path.node;
        for (const field of node.body.body) {
          if (field.type !== "ClassProperty") continue;

          if (field.typeAnnotation && field.typeAnnotation.type === "TSTypeAnnotation" && field.decorators && field.decorators.length > 0) {
            const key = field.key as t.Identifier;
            const serializedType = serializeTypeNode(field.typeAnnotation.typeAnnotation);
            field.decorators.push(decorator(
              t.callExpression(
                t.memberExpression(t.identifier("Reflect"), t.identifier("metadata")), [
                  t.stringLiteral("design:type"),
                  t.logicalExpression("||", serializedType, createIdentifier("Object"))
                ])
            ))
          }
        }
      },
    }
  };
});
```

You can find the full plugin code, and a working sample [here](https://github.com/dragomirtitian/babel-decorators-metadata)

Just as a side not, plugin ordering matters, if `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` comes before our plugin it will have erased all the properties and our plugin will not have the info to emit the decorators anymore. This is the `.babelrc` I tested with and it works, I did not get it to with with any other configuration (but I can't say I tried that hard)

```
  {
    "env": {},
    "ignore": [],
    "plugins": [
      "../plugin/plugin.js",
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
      "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer! Starting from your idea I've developed a plugin too, trying to fill the gap (using `typeof` since `Type || Object` is not safe if use strict is enabled, adding parameter decorators, ensuring import statements are not removed). Here you can find the [babel plugin](https://github.com/leonardfactory/babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata)

Comment: @leonardfactory that plugin is the s*** great job 

Comment: This did not work for me. I am using 'babel-preset-expo'

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately I'm reasonably sure that this is a limitation of using Babel with Typescript. What Babel does, is it simply strips the Typescript typings, [and then treats the code as JavaScript](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/08/27/typescript-and-babel-7/).
Which means babel doesn't care about your `tsconfig.json` [at all](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9028), and thus not `emitDecoratorMetadata` either.

So unfortunately, if you need the decorator metadata, you'll have to stick with `tsc`