# Typescript Decorator and Babel: ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Exercise#name is not defined and cannot be guessed

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs, typeorm, typescript-decorator

Despite having `babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata` installed I have this error below:

```
ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for Exercise#name is not defined and cannot be guessed. 
Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. 
Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).
If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.
```

I have tried this [alternate plugin implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53015862/metadata-retention-with-typescript-babel-7-decorators) but to no avail
I am using typescript and I have `import 'reflect-metadata';` in relevant codes..

**Here are my codes**

Exercise.tsx

```
import {Entity,Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm/browser";


@Entity("Exercise")
export class Exercise{

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!:number;

    @Column()
    name!: Text;

    @Column()
    notes:Text;

    @Column()
    imageJSON:Text;
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": [
      "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
  }
```

snippet of package.json

```
...

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/node": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.66.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
...
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,

  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include":[
    "entities"
  ]
}
```